# How to remove svg inside a div

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am using **D3.js**. This is my **markup**:

```
<div class="graph-container">
    <!--Graph SVG-->
</div>
<div class="graph-container">
    <!--Graph SVG-->
</div>
<div>
    <!--some other SVG-->
</div>
```

I am using the following **JS** to remove all SVG elements:

```
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
```

But I want to remove only the SVGs present inside the class **graph-container**. How can I do that?

Comment: As a sidenote, your class syntax is incorrect, remove the `.`. e.g. `<div class="graph-container">`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d3.selectAll('.graph-container svg').remove();
```

Comment: That should be `.graph-container > svg`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff not really; makes more sense in this case to remove all `svg` elements nested within `.graph-container`

Comment: That's what the selector does -- turns out that both selectors are equivalent in this case though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can do it with CSS, you can use `.graph-container img { display: none; }`. (Assuming it is in an `<img>` tag and the only image in the div is the SVG)